# SQlite (Room) Trigger: two queries

Tags: android, sqlite, triggers, android-sqlite, android-room

I have the following trigger:

```
database.execSQL("DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS Trigger_AfterIncomeRecordInsert");
database.execSQL(
"CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS Trigger_AfterIncomeRecordInsert " +
"AFTER INSERT ON IncomeRecord " +
"BEGIN  " +
"UPDATE FinanceRepeatment SET numOfCreatedRepeatments = numOfCreatedRepeatments +1, " +
"actIncomeRecordId = NEW.id WHERE NEW.financeRepId=FinanceRepeatment.id;" +
"DELETE FROM favourite_tiles WHERE favourite = NEW.id;" +
"END;");
```

If I only use one query either update/delete the query works perfect, however if I want to use both like in this case, I receive the following error: `END expected, got 'DELETE'`

Thats why my question is does SQLITE even support multiple queries like in this case or is the error due to a syntac error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a valid sql statement and should work.

The only reason I can think of that it throws the error is because of a limitation of the method [`execSQL()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#execSQL(java.lang.String)):

> public void execSQL (String sql) 
> Parameters sql String: the SQL statement to be executed.
> **Multiple statements separated by semicolons are not supported.**

A workaround would be to create 2 separate triggers:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trigger_AfterIncomeRecordInsert_1 AFTER INSERT ON IncomeRecord 
BEGIN  
  UPDATE FinanceRepeatment 
  SET numOfCreatedRepeatments = numOfCreatedRepeatments +1, 
      actIncomeRecordId = NEW.id 
  WHERE NEW.financeRepId=FinanceRepeatment.id;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER Trigger_AfterIncomeRecordInsert_2 AFTER INSERT ON IncomeRecord 
BEGIN  
  DELETE FROM favourite_tiles 
  WHERE favourite = NEW.id;
END;
```

Comment: that would sopve my issue, thanks in advance. what about the execution order? is the trigger order always the same or does in depend on some random timestamp 

Comment: @SavanLuffy this is an interesting question for which I did not find anything in the documentation (maybe there is something hidden deeper). Just out of curiosity I tested 2 after insert triggers and I found that the one that was created last executed 1st. When I deleted them both and recreated them in the opposite order the behavior was the same: the one that was created last executed 1st. I can't tell if this is by design.

Comment: thanks for the info. that's interesting. as if sqlite just stores the timestap of which wheb the triggers where created, that's my guess at least